# Blackberry plugin installation issue

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am tryin g to install the blackberry plugin from update site,but while installation its prompting for username and password ,can anyone tell me which authentication is required for this ?

Where should i sign up for installation

Answer (score 2):

First register in [Blackberry Developer zone](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/bdsc/login.pg#register) .  when prompt, give the username and password in the installation. 
Refer the link [howto-install-blackberry-plugin-from-updatesite](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/blackberrydev/howto-start-with-eclipse-blackberry-java-development/install-eclipse-for-blackberry-development/howto-install-blackberry-plugin-from-updatesite/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the username and password which you have provided at the time of signUp on the developer site. The same password and username is required there.

Comment: Thanks for the information,when i am trying to downlad the plugin from update site i am getting an error after 50% of download not able to download,can you please tell me which version of eclipse is required ?

Comment: Thanks for the information,when i am trying to downlad the plugin from update site i am getting an error after 50% of download not able to download,can you please tell me which version of eclipse is required ? I am stuck up with Blackberry setup for development

Comment: i facing issues with setup,its getting installed only 50%

Comment: have you used the above answer ??? its quite clearly say how to do it. just uninstall the eclipse plugin and again start installing. And use eclipse 3.6 for that

Comment: Yes i have tried with eclipse 3.6 and followed the same steps as http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp

Comment: ya its not solved,i am not geting the reason,many of us are facing the same issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8531/discussion-between-bbdev-and-user1195292)